# Could you suggest some tool to draw hexagon diagram when design microservice?

Tags: microservices

I have looked plantUml, and some UML tool that provides community versions, but has not find one yet. 
Thanks

Comment: Very sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Google Drawings](https://docs.google.com/drawings/) extensively now for all our drawing/diagram needs.  It's easy to collaborate with, does everything we need for process and component diagramming and is free to use.